# How to hide drop down list on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I've a `dropdown` menu which looks following like this:

```
<ul>
    <li class="dropdown open">
        <a aria-expanded="true" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-button waves-classic" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span class="user-name">Hi Rajendra! <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
            <img class="img-circle avatar" src="#" alt="" width="40" height="40">
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-list" role="menu" style="">
            <li role="presentation"><a href="profile.html"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out m-r-xs"></i>Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here is a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHSDS.png).

***Problem:***

It shows the dropdown list on page load first time without clicking menu, I tried to use `visibility: hidden` and `display: none`, it hides the list but not shows again after clicking the menu.

Please help me!!

**Help would be appreciated!!**

Comment: Make a working fiddle if possible, with all necessary code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using a framework to handle some of this and I believe just removing the class open will make it appear closed to start with:

```
<ul>
<li class="dropdown">
    <a aria-expanded="true" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-button waves-classic" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="user-name">Hi Rajendra! <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></span>
        <img class="img-circle avatar" src="#" alt="" width="40" height="40">
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-list" role="menu" style="">
        <li role="presentation"><a href="profile.html"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>Profile</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out m-r-xs"></i>Log out</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```